# Sql how to get from 5 weeks startdate and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL server, I'd like to display the date and time period for my reporting.  The time period in the `WHERE` clause is below:

```
WHERE EventDate >= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) -5, 0) 
    AND EventDate <= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

how can I display this in the format: "26 Mar 2017 - 13 Apr 2017"

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Those functions are product specific.

Comment: Add the tag sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the period from 5 weeks ago to 5 weeks in the future.

You could try the following:

```
-- etc
WHERE EventDate BETWEEN dateadd(week,-5,getdate()) AND dateadd(week,5,getdate());
```

If you want to display the dates, you can try this:

```
SELECT format(dateadd(week,-5,getdate()),'d MMM yyyy') +' - '+ format(dateadd(week,5,getdate()),'d MMM yyyy');
```

Comment: Yes but I would like to display in my report the starting date and the end date of this 5 weeks. If I put this date in my tablix, the tablix displays every Date Value. I will only the starting and the ending.                                                for example: 26 Mar 2017 - 13 Apr 2017

Comment: I don’t think that’s what you are implying in the question. Do you want values in the `WHERE` clause or do you want to `SELECT` them?

Comment: I would like to select them, sorry for my bad explanation in my question

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is see the dates, just use select:

```
select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) -5, 0)
    , dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

If you want to see the format: "26 Mar 2017 - 13 Apr 2017":

```
select cast(dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) -5, 0) as varchar(20)) + 
    ' - ' + 
    cast(dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0) as varchar(20))
```

Comment: thanks thats it, bur if I insert it in my tablix then it didn´t stop  the report. it appears a runtime error

Comment: I can't comment on tablix, I've never used it before.  I suggest you ask another question in the appropriate place.  In the mean time, if this answered your question, please accept the answer.  Thanks!